# std::function constructor and nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does the following code prints "0" as the output?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef void (*fp_t)();

    fp_t fp = nullptr;

    std::function<void()> f = fp;
    std::cout << (f == nullptr) << '\n';
}
```

I've tested it both with gcc 4.7.2 and MSVC-11.0.

I think that it's should print "1" because of the following quote from the standard:

**ISO/IEC 14882:2011**

20.8.11.2.1 function construct/copy/destroy [func.wrap.func.con]

> `template<class F> function(F f);`
>   `template<class F, class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a, F f);`
>
> ...
>
> 8 *Postconditions:* `!*this` if any of the following hold: — `f` is a `NULL`
>   function pointer. — `f` is a `NULL` pointer to member. — `F` is an instance
>   of the function class template, and `!f`

Comment: `!*this` does not imply that `this == nullptr` is true. One uses `operator bool` and the other uses `operator==`.

Comment: I would say they should compare equal, though. Equality to `nullptr` compares true if it's empty, and initializing it with a null function pointer makes it empty.

Comment: @chris: According to 20.8.11.2.6/1, `f == nullptr` returns `!f`. I tend to believe this is a bug

Comment: @AndyProwl, Agreed. My first comment was solely based on which function was called and that they don't always have to do the same thing. In the case of `std::function`, it turns out they do.

Comment: Just tested this exact code in VC2010, it prints 1. Looking at <functional>, line 270 explicitly declares comparison operator with nullptr: `bool operator==(const function<_Fty>& _Other, _Unutterable) { return (!_Other); }`. If it prints 0 for you, open the header file and look for == operator - maybe the messed something up?

Comment: `nullptr == f`, `f == nullptr`, `!f` and `!!f` all give the correct results on VC++10. Can't test on VC++11 yet as it's _still_ doing an update :|

Comment: This is now http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57465

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is a bug. Per paragraph 20.8.11.2.6/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> ```
> template <class R, class... ArgTypes>
> bool operator==(const function<R(ArgTypes...)>& f, nullptr_t) noexcept;
>
> template <class R, class... ArgTypes>
> bool operator==(nullptr_t, const function<R(ArgTypes...)>& f) noexcept;
> ```
>
> 1 ***Returns*: `!f`**.

Therefore, `(f == nullptr)` should evaluate to `true` if and only if `!f` evaluates to `true`. Then, paragraph 20.8.11.2.1/8 specifies:

> ```
> template<class F> function(F f);
> template <class F, class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a, F f);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> 8 **Postconditions: `!*this` if any of the following hold**:
>
> > — **`f` is a NULL function pointer.**
> >
> > [...]

Since `fp` is a null function pointer, the above paragraph should guarantee that after initialization of `f` from `fp`, the expression `!f` evaluates to `true`. Which in turn means, that the comparison with `nullptr` should return `true` (by § 20.8.11.2.6/1).

Which in turns means, that this is a bug.

Comment: So strange... Both gcc 4.7.2 and MSVC-11.0 gives this output

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: Yes, it is strange indeed. FWIW, Clang gives the output I expect

Comment: And for this expression - if (!f) { /* ... */ } what should be happened? Does it call operator bool() or smth like this?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: Yes, that is contextually converted to `bool` (the `explicit operator bool()` of `std::function` will be invoked)

Comment: in case of constructing std::function object with nullptr, does it really have a target and what should be returned for the expression if (!f) { /* ... */ } according to the standard?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: If constructing from a `nullptr`, it does not have a target and `!f` evaluates to `true`

Comment: Oh, this bug is reproduced even with boost. Try the following code - http://pastie.org/7981295

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: Yes, that seems to be the case

Comment: But why boost have the same bug? I think that it's have their own set of overloaded oeprators

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: I don't know why there is a bug, I just know the Standard is pretty clear about what the behavior should be (see the answer)

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: Sorry I could not help any better

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but some details (gcc) too large for a comment:

Function is checked for validity with

```
template<typename _Signature>
  static bool
  _M_not_empty_function(const function<_Signature>& __f)
  { return static_cast<bool>(__f); }

template<typename _Tp>
  static bool
  _M_not_empty_function(const _Tp*& __fp)
  { return __fp; }

template<typename _Class, typename _Tp>
  static bool
  _M_not_empty_function(_Tp _Class::* const& __mp)
  { return __mp; }

template<typename _Tp>
  static bool
  _M_not_empty_function(const _Tp&)
  { return true; }
```

Probably

```
template<typename _Tp>
  static bool
  _M_not_empty_function(const _Tp*& __fp)
  { return __fp; }
```

is intended to work with functional pointers, buit it doesn't. Instead general case is used that is probably intended  for functional objects only.

```
template<typename _Tp>
    static bool
    M_not_empty_function(const _Tp*& __fp)
    { return __fp; }

int main()
{
    typedef void (*fp_t)();
    fp_t fp = nullptr;
    return  M_not_empty_function(fp);
}
```

generates

```
error: no matching function for call to 'M_not_empty_function(void (*&)())'
note: candidate is:
note: template<class _Tp> bool M_not_empty_function(const _Tp*&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   types 'const _Tp' and 'void()' have incompatible cv-qualifiers
```

Comment: Thanks for debugging this for me, I'll get it fixed in GCC asap :)