# Strange behavior with std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I'm using the standard function wrapper from the C++11 library, and I am seeing some strange behavior with its boolean operator. If I create a `std::function` object the boolean operator returns false. This is still true if I assign `nullptr` to the object and check again. The problem appears when I assign it a void pointer which I have cast into a function pointer. Consider the following program:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void* Test() {
    return nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::function<void()> foo;
    std::cout << !!foo << std::endl;

    foo = nullptr;
    std::cout << !!foo << std::endl;

    foo = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(Test());
    std::cout << !!foo << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What I expect as output is `0 0 0` but the result is `0 0 1` (see [demo](http://ideone.com/1JA0Zc)). Can anyone explain why the boolean operator returns true when it contains a null, non-callable function pointer? And please also mention a workaround to check for `nullptr` in `std::function`

NOTE: I've already tried checking if the target is null (with `foo.target<void*>() == nullptr`) instead of using the boolean operator, but it seems as if no matter what the function object contains, the target is always null (even when the function object is perfectly fine with being called).

Comment: [clang++3.4 output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ad19ac2ae8bc716): `0 0 0`

Comment: This looked familiar to me, and indeed, it might be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16823501/420683 (besides the UB problem, see Daniel Frey's answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. First, here's a [simplified example](http://ideone.com/QLw6E2) that doesn't play any games with casts:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*VF)();

VF Test() {
    return nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::function<void()> foo(Test());
    std::cout << !!foo << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It still prints 1 with GCC. It shouldn't:

> **20.8.11.2.1**
>   `template<class F> function(F f);`
>   `template <class F, class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a, F f);`
>   **7** *Requires:* `F`
>   shall be `CopyConstructible`. `f` shall be `Callable` (20.8.11.2) for
>   argument types `ArgTypes` and return type `R`. The copy constructor and
>   destructor of `A` shall not throw exceptions.
>   **8** *Postconditions:* `!*this`
>   if any of the following hold:
>
> - `f` is a `NULL` function pointer.
> - `f` is a `NULL` pointer to member.
> - `F` is an instance of the function class template, and `!f`

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57465 (also see the question linked in my comment to the OP)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the code is doing what you think it does. This line:

```
foo = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(Test());
```

means that you receive a `void*` from `Test()`. You then procede to `reinterpret_cast` this **pointer-to-object** into a **pointer-to-function**. This is not allowed and therefore the code yields undefined behavior and therefore any output of the compiler is valid.

The relevant parts of the standard are

> #### 5.2.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]
>
> <sup>8</sup> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with dierent cv- qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.
>
> <sup>9</sup> The null pointer value (4.10) is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type. [*Note:* A null pointer constant of type `std::nullptr_t` cannot be converted to a pointer type, and a null pointer constant of integral type is not necessarily converted to a null pointer value. *— end note* ]

and

> #### 4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]
>
> <sup>1</sup> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* **of that type** and is **distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type**.

(emphasis mine)

Here's a reduced test case taking `std::function` (and its possible bugs) out of the equation:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using fp_t = void(*)();
    void* vn = nullptr;
    fp_t foo = reinterpret_cast<fp_t>(vn); // GCC: warning, Clang: silence
    //fp_t foo = reinterpret_cast<fp_t>(nullptr); // error (GCC and Clang!)
    std::cout << !!foo << std::endl;
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bc9722f228bdabb)

Comment: I'm not sure it's UB, see [expr.reinterpret.cast]/8+9 (8 says it's implementation-defined, but as a general rule, nullptr value -> nullptr value)

Comment: @DyP /9 doesn't apply AFAICT, `Test()` returns a `void*`, not `0` or `std::nullptr_t`. Looking into /8, I think it doesn't apply either as it seems to require *two* conversions, back-and-forth. Oh, and GCC gives you a [warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12bc85769aa8ae06) about what I wrote in my answer :) Clang for some reason accepts the code without warning and prints three zeros. Doesn't mean much when UB is involved.

Comment: Hmm for a moment I thought a `void*` would be an *object pointer*, too (as opposed to *function pointer*). Well that would mean you cannot convert between a `void*` and a function pointer at all? /9 could apply (apart from the conversion issue), as `Test()` returns a null pointer value ("A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the
result is the *null pointer value*")

Comment: Cast from `void*` is a red herring. [The problem remains](http://ideone.com/0U1ZGJ) if `Test` is made to return a `NULL` function pointer, with no cast in sight.

Comment: Oh, I was indeed correct assuming `void*` is an object pointer type: [basic.compound]/3

Comment: @DyP I added 4.10 with some emphasis. I think this means that the null pointer value of one type is not convertable to the null pointer value of another type.

Comment: " I think this means that the null pointer value of one type is not convertable to the null pointer value of another type." Sure it is convertable o.O [expr.reinterpret.cast]/9 says so. Similarly, [expr.static.cast]/11.

Comment: (I got confused for a second with the casts in clang++) the emphasized part of [conv.ptr] means AFAIK that `nullptr != ptr` for every valid (dereferenceable w/o UB) pointer `ptr`; however `(int*)nullptr == (int*)(double*)nullptr` should be defined behaviour, yielding `true` (and requires only an implicit cast for the first conversion as per [conv.ptr]/1)

Comment: @DyP I meant "not in *all* cases". Of course it's convertible, e.g. Base->Derived, etc. For any two types where no such explicit wording exists, the result of the conversion is undefined like for pointer-to-object and pointer-to-function. And /8 still has "...if an implementation supports..." in it.

Comment: I agree: for any conversion where there's no specified behaviour, it's UB (or ID), therefore the result of the conversion is undefined. My original comment was interpreting /9 as "if the conversion from an object pointer type to a function pointer type is allowed, it should yield the null pointer value of the destination type", but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @DyP While I think the UB means anything could happen, it would most likely not cause a problem. GCC seems to point it out with the warning but that should be it, it doesn't *really* explain the result we are seeing. And then there's Igor's answer which shows that GCC seems to have a bug in this area independent of the UB of the `reinterpret_cast`.