# Check if returned std::function is "valid" in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, task-queue

I want to implement a dynamic task queue like so:

```cpp
typedef std::function<void(void)> Job;
typedef std::function<Job(void)> JobGenerator;

// ..

JobGenerator gen = ...;
auto job = gen(); 
while (IsValidFunction(job))
{
    job();
}
```

How can i implement `IsValidFunction`? Is there a sort of default value for `std::function` to check against?

Comment: I'm not clear what makes it valid. What do you mean by exists?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool

Comment: Is it maybe `while(job)` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply check `job` as a bool:

```
while (auto job = gen())
{
    job();
}
```

That's a sort of shorthand which assigns `job` from `gen()` each time through the loop, stopping when `job` evaluates as false, relying on `std::function<>::operator bool`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool

Comment: Good stuff. I already knew about [conversion operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383606/conversion-operators-in-c), but I forgot about them entirely! I think, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600295/what-is-the-meaning-of-operator-bool-const-in-c) explains the concept better.

Comment: Careful @Domi, there are bugs on the `bool`  conversion of `std::function` in the wild: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578237/strange-behavior-with-stdfunction

Answer (score 1):

You could just check if the function has a valid target, by using its [conversion to `bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool). Non-valid functions would then be empty ones which don't have a target, e.g. default-constructed ones or `nullptr`.